# Ruby - File.open(text_file.txt) is not able to find the file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is probably a simple "Navigating directory" problem since I'm new but..

Inside of a file named `tasks_lists.rb` I am attempting to save the text inside of a text file to a variable named `draft`.

Here is that code:

```
class FivePoints::Tasks


 attr_accessor :draft, :efile, :serve

  def self.start
    binding.pry
    draft = File.open("./text_files/draft.txt")
    efile = File.open("./text_files/efile.txt")
    serve = File.open("./text_files/serve.txt")
    self.new(draft, efile, serve)
  end

  def initialize(draft , efile, serve)
    @draft = draft
    @efile = efile
    @serve = serve
  end
end
```

I have tried to `pry` around, but no luck. I have also tried variations such as `("../text_files/efile.txt")`, `("/text_files/efile.txt")`. I will attach an image of the directory tree as well.

[image]

I am simply trying to eventually `puts` out some text in the CLI for a sample program. That text will be in the `draft.txt` file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to run this locally, then find out the path of the file (you can view its properties from file explorer), and use that explicitly in your code.

Find the exact path (If you're on UNIX it'll be something like /home/USER/projects/five_points/bla....) then replace your string with the exact full path and you'll be able to open the files as needed

Comment: Should it be able to call on the file without using the exact path?

Comment: The only difference I can find between my program and a simple one like [link](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/writing-to-file-ruby) is that mine are not on the same level in the directory?

Comment: If you have set up your Rails app to properly account for the path, then you should be able to call Rails.root.join('lib', 'five_points', 'text_files', 'draft.txt')

Comment: If you really want to avoid using the full path, open up a console. and see what Rails.root.join('lib', 'five_points', 'text_files', 'draft.txt') returns. Keep on playing with that until it matches your local path exactly.

Comment: I've never used Rails with this. The interface is currently just the CLI. I created the default files by Bundle gem <file_name> and then I've only added files. How can I make it so the `Rails.root.join` function works?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your files are in a directory called `five_points` but your code is under `lib` so one level higher ?

Also, you need to be sure you open the file for appending.

```
draft = File.open("./five_points/text_files/draft.txt", "a")
```

Comment: The active file is actually in `lib` as well. It is `tasks_lists.rb` in the `lists` folder. So there should be no need to go into `five_points`

Comment: Your example in your code you're trying to access `draft.txt` which is under `text_files` which is under `five_points` which is under `lib`. Are you saying the code snipped you inserted is from `taaks_lists.rb` and not `five_points.rb`?  If it's called from `five_points.rb` then the start position is still before `five_points`.

Comment: At the `binding.pry` in the `start` method, type in `Dir.pwd` and see what the working directory is.

Comment: So the working directory is ` "C:/Users/AustinBurke/Documents/Austin/Personal_Projects/Development/five_points"`

Comment: And in the execution file, I require all the files in lib via `require './lib/five_points'`

Comment: Huh.  So it should work as you did it.  You could try `File.open("#{Dir.pwd}/text_files/draft.txt"). Although it's building an absolute path it will change based on where the project is located.